# While statement crashes tab in Repl.it (P5.js)

Tags: javascript, while-loop, replit

I have a project due on the 27th, and I have encountered a problem. Repl.it crashes whenever I boot up my program. If you look at my code, on line 42:

```
//getting a number that isnt the players door or the prize door
  while ((randomDoor2 == prizeDoor) || (randomDoor2 == randomDoor)) {
    setTimeout(
      function(){ 
        randomDoor2 = Math.round(random(1,3));
      }, 
      10000);
  }
```

there is a while loop. Commenting that out makes the code work perfectly with no lag.

I have no idea what I should try and do.

It might be something other than my while, so here is my entire script.js:

```
var chance; // swap | dont swap
var prizeDoor;
var randomDoor;
var randomDoor2;
var randomDoor3;
var decide;

function setup() {
  chance = 50;
  createCanvas(1000,1000);
}

function draw() {
 //setting up round

  prizeDoor = Math.round(random(1,3));

  //choosing first door

  console.log("[1] [2] [3]");
  randomDoor = Math.round(random(1,3));

  //showing user the door AI picks
var chance = 50; // swap | dont swap
var prizeDoor;
var randomDoor;
var randomDoor2;
var randomDoor3;
var decide;

function setup() {
  chance = 50;
  createCanvas(1000,1000);
}

function draw() {
 //setting up round

  prizeDoor = Math.round(random(1,3));

  //choosing first door

  console.log("[1] [2] [3]");
  randomDoor = Math.round(random(1,3));

  //showing user the door AI picks

  if (randomDoor == 1) {
    console.log(" ^");
    console.log(" |");
  } else if (randomDoor == 2) {
    console.log("     ^");
    console.log("     |");
  } else {
    console.log("         ^");
    console.log("         |");
  }

  console.log("AI chooses door #" + randomDoor + ".");

  //revealing a door

  //getting a number that isnt the players door or the prize door
  while ((randomDoor2 == prizeDoor) || (randomDoor2 == randomDoor)) {
    setTimeout(
      function(){ 
        randomDoor2 = Math.round(random(1,3));
      }, 
      10000);
  }

  //showing this to the user
  console.log("");
  console.log("Door #" + randomDoor2 + " does not have the prize.");

  //having the computer make a desicion
  if (random(0,100) < chance) {
    decide = "swap doors.";
    while ((randomDoor3 !== randomDoor2) || (randomDoor3 !==  randomDoor)) {
      randomDoor3 = Math.round(random(1,3));
    }
  } else {
    decide = "keep the current door.";
  }

  //letting the user know of the computer's desicion
  console.log("");
  console.log("The AI chose to " + decide);

  // figuring out if the AI won
  if (randomDoor3 == prizeDoor || randomDoor == prizeDoor) {

    console.log("AI won!");

    if (decide == "swap doors.") {
      chance -= 5;
    } else {
      chance += 5;
    }
  } else {

    console.log("AI lost.");

    if (decide == "swap doors.") {
      chance += 5;
    } else {
      chance -= 5;
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted the while statement to find the door that is not the chosen door nor the door with the prize, but instead it crashes.

Comment: random function?

Comment: This code was written with the P5.js library, so yes there is a random function

Comment: setTimeout is asynchronous so now your randomDoor2 also will never change for while loop. by asking for adding a timeout i dint mean to use setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was actually pretty easy, just change some operators. Here is the final piece of code:

```
var chance = 50; // swap | dont swap
var prizeDoor;
var randomDoor;
var randomDoor2;
var randomDoor3;
var decide;

function setup() {
  chance = 50;
  createCanvas(1000,1000);
}

function draw() {
 //setting up round

  prizeDoor = Math.round(random(1,3));

  //choosing first door

  console.log("[1] [2] [3]");
  randomDoor = Math.round(random(1,3));

  //showing user the door AI picks

  if (randomDoor == 1) {
    console.log(" ^");
    console.log(" |");
  } else if (randomDoor == 2) {
    console.log("     ^");
    console.log("     |");
  } else {
    console.log("         ^");
    console.log("         |");
  }

  console.log("AI chooses door #" + randomDoor + ".");

  //revealing a door

  //getting a number that isnt the players door or the prize door
  while ((randomDoor2 == prizeDoor) || (randomDoor2 == randomDoor)) {
    setTimeout(
      function(){ 
        randomDoor2 = Math.round(random(1,3));
      }, 
      10000);
  }

  //showing this to the user
  console.log("");
  console.log("Door #" + randomDoor2 + " does not have the prize.");

  //having the computer make a desicion
  if (random(0,100) < chance) {
    decide = "swap doors.";
    while ((randomDoor3 == randomDoor2) || (randomDoor3 ==  randomDoor)) {
      randomDoor3 = Math.round(random(1,3));
    }
  } else {
    decide = "keep the current door.";
  }

  //letting the user know of the computer's desicion
  console.log("");
  console.log("The AI chose to " + decide);

  // figuring out if the AI won
  if (randomDoor3 == prizeDoor || randomDoor == prizeDoor) {

    console.log("AI won!");

    if (decide == "swap doors.") {
      chance -= 5;
    } else {
      chance += 5;
    }
  } else {

    console.log("AI lost.");

    if (decide == "swap doors.") {
      chance += 5;
    } else {
      chance -= 5;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit i got the code to work did change up a few bits to make it work on my end like the math.random but shouldn't be hard to change back also new to stackoverflow so took me a while to figure out the code snippet pasting :p.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var chance; // swap | dont swap
var prizeDoor;
var randomDoor;
var randomDoor2;
var randomDoor3;
var decide;
var chance = 50;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000,1000);
}

function draw() {
 //setting up round

  prizeDoor = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  console.log(prizeDoor+" prizeDoor");

  //choosing first door
  console.log("[1] [2] [3]");
  randomDoor = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  randomDoor2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  randomDoor3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);


  //showing user the door AI picks

  if (randomDoor == 1) {
    console.log(" ^");
    console.log(" |");
  } else if (randomDoor == 2) {
    console.log("     ^");
    console.log("     |");
  } else {
    console.log("         ^");
    console.log("         |");
  }



  console.log("AI chooses door #" + randomDoor + ".");


  //revealing a door

  //getting a number that isnt the players door or the prize door
  while ((randomDoor2 == prizeDoor) || (randomDoor2 == randomDoor)) {
   randomDoor2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  }

  //showing this to the user
  console.log("");
  console.log("Door #" + randomDoor2 + " does not have the prize.");

  //having the computer make a desicion
  if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) < chance) {
    decide = "swap doors.";
    while ((randomDoor3 == randomDoor2) || (randomDoor3 == randomDoor)) {
      randomDoor3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    }
  } else {
    randomDoor3 = randomDoor;
    decide = "keep the current door.";
  }

  //letting the user know of the computer's desicion
  console.log("");
  console.log("The AI chose to " + decide);

  // figuring out if the AI won
  if (randomDoor3 == prizeDoor) {

    console.log("AI won!");

    if (decide == "swap doors.") {
      chance -= 5;
    } else {
      chance += 5;
    }
  } else {

    console.log("AI lost.");

    if (decide == "swap doors.") {
      chance += 5;
    } else {
      chance -= 5;
    }
  }
}

draw();
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it, my code now works, but still crashes. You did it halfway ;)

Comment: W8 a minute i think this is what you ment to do.
  while ((randomDoor2 == prizeDoor) || (randomDoor2 == randomDoor)) {
   randomDoor2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
   console.log(randomDoor2);
  }

This makes it so that RandomDoor2 is never == to randomDoor or PrizeDoor

Comment: Tried that, still crashes, randomDoor2 is ```undefined```

Comment: Also because the chance = 50; is in another function the ai will never swap the door. putting it with the other variables in the top will fix this problem

Comment: if with || it never terminates then surely with && it will never enter the while loop. @DjimSchaap

Comment: @AZ_ yea you'r right about that one got it working now hope it helps him.

Comment: random numbers are 1,2 & 3 so say first two numbers prizedoor and randomdoor are 1 &2 or any other two of these 3, now in while loop you are changing the third number until it's not the rest of these 3 which makes no sense why not simply set it to the third one? @DjimSchaap

Comment: Because PrizeDoor and RandomDoor are randomly generated within the range of 1 to 3 and he wants RandomDoor2 to NOT equal Prizedoor or RandomDoor so with this while loop RandomDoor2 will never be the same as PrizeDoor or RandomDoor and it isn't hardcoded what door is the prize either this way.

Comment: I do understand its not hard coded but my point is why a while loop cuz using while you are not sure after how many loops you will get the third one, but when you know the other two number getting the third one is quite easy and faster and correct way to go like [1,2,3].filter(e => e!==randomdoor&& e!== prizedoor)

Comment: @AZ_ I didn't know about the filter function i am not that experienced in javascript yet and wanted to use the authors original code as much as possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

you are creating two random numbers consecutively prizeDoor & randomDoor, so same numbers to be generated using Math.random on two consecutive hits is quite hard to happen.

In your while loop you are expecting your new random number to match your both previous random numbers now for one hit/compilation they can be same or cannot be if they are not same its useless to have your while loop it will will never terminate,

say a=1 and b=2

now 
expecting c==a && c==b will never happen cuz a!=b;

changing c in while loop will make no difference.
so your logic is completely wrong, let us know what you are trying to achieve maybe then we can help to build up the logic

```js
let random = () => Math.random() * 3;
let prizeDoor = Math.round(random());
console.log('prizeDoor', prizeDoor)
let randomDoor = Math.round(random());
console.log('randomDoor', randomDoor)
```

Comment: Added a ten-second timeout, still crashes.

Comment: Sorry, didnt update my code. I am currently using || in my while, will update.

Comment: == with & and != with or (|) are the same things

Answer (score 0):

random() is a method of Math object.
It worked for me by replacing all the random() method calls with Math.random().